# Prpoblem in ggsave() with ggscatterhist()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have am annoying problem with the ggsave() function of the package ggplot2 by doing scatterhist() diagrams with packahe ggpubr.

Below the example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


Graph1 <- ggscatterhist(
 iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width",
 color = "Species", size = 3, alpha = 0.6,
 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
 margin.params = list(fill = "Species", color = "black", size = 0.2)
)
```

Here the problem, I try to save the graph and:

```
ggsave(plot=Graph1, filename="Grafico1.png", device="png", dpi=500)

Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('ggscatterhist', 'list')"
```

In this way, removing the plot definition it works fine, but I am not feeling comfortable with this. Is this perhap a bug?

```
ggsave(filename="Grafico1.png", device="png", dpi=500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we address to documentation it says:

> an object of class ggscatterhist, which is list of ggplots, including
> the following elements:...

So Graph1 is not a ggplot object but list of three ggplot objects:
`Graph1$sp`:

[image]

`Graph1$xplot`:

[image]

and `Graph1$yplot`:

[image]

So you can't reliably use ggplot object specific functions like ggsave for `ggscatterhist` objects without without thorough investigation into their nature.
Answering your question if it is a bug I would answer no. `ggsave(filename="Grafico1.png", device="png", dpi=500)` is working without any erros as it is saving current graphic device that contains plot outputs of all `ggscatterhist` list elements.

Should you decide to use other graphic devices try `Cairo` package as well:

```
library(Cairo)

Cairo(600, 600, file="Grafico1.png", type="png", bg="white")
Graph1 
dev.off()
```

The above listed code will reliably give you the desired `Grafico1.png` file.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply run:

```r
Graph1;ggsave(filename="Grafico1.png", device="png", dpi=500)
```

This will first re-plot your object and ggsave will then save the last plot.